# Set <span> tags under <li> tag in TYPO3

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I am inserting `<span>` tags under `<li>` like this.

```
lib.parseFunc.tags {
  li = TEXT
  li {
    current = 1
    wrap = <li><span>|</span></li>
  }
}
```

Since `<li>` tags are defined as TEXT cObject, the `<a>` tags set from Ckeditor under `<li>` are also treated as TEXT cObject and the links are displaying like `t3://page?uid=18` which are not accessible.

Does anyone know how can I parse `<a>` tags as links but doesn't affect the `<li>` configuration? Thanks

Comment: Why are you inserting those span wrappers in the first place?

Comment: Since it is required for styling purpose?!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do with those spans? I guess CSS pseudo classes (like `:before`) should also be sufficient. If you still need some more custom styling, you can also add your own style classes via the RTE GUI, see https://www.clickstorm.de/blog/der-neue-typo3-rte-ckeditor/ for examples (e.g. "check-list" class at `<ul>` tags).

Comment: Thank you Michael, I have tried `:before` or adding class and change the styling. Eventually It will work with some hard code in CSS. But I would like to know whether it is possible through TYPOSCRIPT to declare the `<a>` tags under `<li>` tags as typolinks. I have tried 

    tags {
         a = TEXT
         a {
            stdWrap.current = 1
            stdWrap.typolink.extTarget = _blank
            stdWrap.typolink.target = {$cLinkTagTarget}
            stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = parameters : allParams
          }
    }

But doesn't work